# Vim, how to delete from CURRENT cursor position, until end of line and next N lines?

Tags: vim, vi

This is strangely difficult to figure out.  I do not want to delete what is to the left of the cursor, only from the cursor to the end of the line, and the following 3 lines in ONE command.  I know I could do `d$ and 3dd`

Comment: There's no newline after that `fourth The..` line, is there?

Comment: That must have been the problem, thanks!  I see your solution is valid as well now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, `3dd` deletes what is to the left of the cursor.

You want `4D`.

Comment: Or, since `D` essentially is `d$`, `4d$`, the solution that OP [arrived at](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177603/vim-how-to-delete-from-current-cursor-position-until-end-of-line-and-next-n-li/177604?noredirect=1#comment293965_177604).

Comment: Thanks!  I actually said, d$ followed by 3dd on the next line, which accomplishes this in 2 commands, but 4D is exactly what I wanted, and is shorted than the 4d$ that I arrived at.

Answer (score 2):

Try `d:+4` (from here till the beginning of the fourth line from here).

Comment: It does not seem to do exactly what I am asking for, in fact I am not exactly sure how that command is being interpreted, but it behaves a bit unexpectedly.

Comment: I figured it out, the answer was d4$

Comment: The problem is that d: +4 is not inclusive of the next 4 lines, it only gets the next 3 lines, which was tripping me up.

Comment: It is, in fact, inclusive, but `vim` is not able to move the beginning of the fourth line from here when there are only three lines after. Still, I will leave this answer here as an alternate.

Comment: I am sorry, your answer was completely valid, I was wrong!

Comment: Not completely valid, but still, thanks! Can I interest you in the Area51 proposal on `vim`: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80441/vi-and-vim?